# an ssh subsystem that does ls

Tags: ssh, openssh, ls

Normally you create a subsystem by doing `Subsystem vim /usr/bin/vim` or something like that. So how would I do a subsystem that did `ls -la`? ie. you call the ls subsystem, it gives you an ls and then closes the channel. It doesn't seem like `Subsystem vim ls -la` would work since it's not a path to a binary file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include command-line arguments in a `Subsystem` definition. Here is part of the "Subsystem" description from the [sshd_config documentation](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5?query=sshd_config&sec=5):

> Subsystem
>       Configures an external subsystem (e.g. file transfer daemon). Arguments should be
>       a subsystem name and a command **(with optional arguments)** to execute upon 
>       subsystem request.

So this should work fine:

```
Subsystem ls ls -la /some/directory
```

Sshd runs the subsystem command as a shell command, so the command may contain shell syntax:

```
Subsystem ls ls -la /some/dir | tr a-z A-Z     # Upper-cases output
```

Another approach would be to write a simple script that runs the desired command, and set sshd to run the script as the subsystem command. For example, create a script containing these lines and mark it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ls -la
```

Then set the subsystem to run the script:

```
Subsystem ls /path/to/my/script
```